Rambam: Thou Shalt Not Be an Idiot
According to this article:

I think racism violates some important meta-principles of the Torah,
particularly the thinking of Maimonides, for whom there is a 614th
commandment, Thou Shalt Not Be an Idiot.

Obviously this is a tongue-in-cheek paraphrase rather than a direct quote from Rambam. But can anyone point me to where Rambam might hint at that sort of idea? Many thanks.

What's your definition of racism?

https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.11.16

@shmosel I don’t have one. I was quoting an article, as you can see.
